# alsa on my target device says "cannot find card'0'"

Tags: audio, pcm, alsa

I'm trying to enable my target's sound card to work through ALSA, it's a Qualcomm MSM8660 Snapdragon which means there is no pci devices and running a kind of embedded linux.

Because this device is originally a commercial android phone so I'm sure it has proper built-in audio drivers on its kernel but ALSA doesn't recognize audiocards at all.

I believe this is because I didn't write any of alsa configuration files like /etc/asound.conf and /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf (I tried the default alsa.conf that comes with its build source but no luck)

what it says with the below commands are:

```
/dev # ls pcm*
pcmC0D0c  pcmC0D0p  pcmC0D1c  pcmC0D1p


/dev # cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [msmaudio       ]:  - msm-audio
                      msm-audio


/dev # cat /proc/asound/devices 
  0: [ 0]   : control
 16: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
 17: [ 0- 1]: digital audio playback
 24: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
 25: [ 0- 1]: digital audio capture
 33:        : timer


/dev # cat /proc/asound/pcm
00-00: DSP 1 msm-codec-dai-0 :  : playback 2 : capture 1
00-01: MVS mvs-codec-dai-1 :  : playback 1 : capture 1


/dev # cat /proc/asound/timers 
G0: system timer : 10000.000us (10000000 ticks)
P0-0-0: PCM playback 0-0-0 : SLAVE
P0-0-1: PCM capture 0-0-1 : SLAVE
P0-0-2: PCM playback 0-0-2 : SLAVE
P0-1-0: PCM playback 0-1-0 : SLAVE
P0-1-1: PCM capture 0-1-1 : SLAVE


/dev # cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/info 
card: 0
device: 0
subdevice: 0
stream: PLAYBACK
id: DSP 1 msm-codec-dai-0
name: 
subname: subdevice #0
class: 0
subclass: 0
subdevices_count: 2
subdevices_avail: 2


/dev # cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm1p/info 
card: 0
device: 1
subdevice: 0
stream: PLAYBACK
id: MVS mvs-codec-dai-1
name: 
subname: subdevice #0
class: 0
subclass: 0
subdevices_count: 1
subdevices_avail: 1
```

Please let me know what I should do to make it play.

I appreciate in advance.

Have a great day.

---

I added the default alsa.conf of the official alsa-lib source to /usr/share/also and wrote a very simple asound.conf at /etc

```
pcm.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

and the result is,

```
/temp # aplay- l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: msmaudio [msm-audio], device 0: DSP 1 msm-codec-dai-0 []
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
card 0: msmaudio [msm-audio], device 1: MVS mvs-codec-dai-1 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

so the problem was configuration files, I got another problem that aplay is stuck at

```
/temp # aplay -i ./gbb.mp3
...
...
access("//.asoundrc", R_OK)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/snd/controlC0", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl64(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
ioctl(3, SNDRV_CTL_IOCTL_PVERSION or USBDEVFS_CONTROL or USBDEVFS_CONTROL32, 0xbedb085c) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDRV_CTL_IOCTL_PCM_PREFER_SUBDEVICE, 0xbedb0880) = 0
open("/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC
...
...
```

but I guess this isn't about configuration any more.

Comment: I assume you are running Android. Can you do `alsa_aplay -l` and see if your card is listed?

Comment: Hi Omair, this OS isn't Android and I just succeeded to show the card list by placing the default alsa.conf into /usr/share/alsa.